# How do I loop through a single column of dates in Google Sheets and then send an email based on the date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to loop through a single column of dates (in format dd/mm/yyyy) in a range C2:C

Inside the loop, I want to send an email if the date is over one year old as the membership has expired.

The email address for the member is in the adjacent column

I am having problems working with dates and cannot figure out how to make the if statement understand if the date is over one year old. I can do this on a spreadsheet but it doesn't translate to JS

I'm not even close to having a working method on this, I don't fully understand all the getActive, getRange and getDataValues parts and can't find a place that explains using these. Any pointers in where I can look would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it easiest to convert dates to milliseconds using `.getTime()`.

This return the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01. [Ref here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp).

So what I would do is:

```
function sendMailIfMembershipExpired() {

  var today = new Date().getTime(); // Get today's date
  var yearInMs = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // 1yr worth of milliseconds

  // Get sheet with data;  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("NAME_OF_SHEET_WITH_DATA");

  // Get the data from the sheet
  // Col C for dates and Col D for email addresses
  var data = ss.getRange("C2:D").getValues();

  // Define variables
  var dateInCell, difference, emailTo;

  // Loop through data
  for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) { // data array starts at 0

    dateInCell = new Date(data[row][0]).getTime(); // Get date from sheet in milliseconds

    difference = today - dateInCell; // Get difference in millisenconds

    if ( difference > yearInMs ) { // Check if membership has expired

      emailTo = data[row][1]; // Get email address

      GmailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, "Membership expired", "Hello, your membership has expired"); // Send email

    }    
  }
}
```

The Google Apps Script docs are pretty good. Refs are here

1. [Get Sheet by name](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String))
2. [Get values from sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
3. [Send mail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String))

---

### **Edit**

[@dwmorrin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11359233/dwmorrin) is correct.

As long as the dates in the sheet are formatted as dates and not text, you can simplify to

```
dateInCell = data[row][0].getTime(); // Get date from sheet in milliseconds
```

Comment: Thank you, I am going to get my head around this tomorrow evening as I have done too much today.

I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Something to consider: `data[row][0]` is probably already a Date instance (default behavior in Sheets) so `new Date(data[row[0])` is redundant (and if its a string "dd/mm/yyyy", it will get it wrong, try it).

Comment: I'm still struggling with this, it may well be due to what dwmorrin states, that the dates already in the sheet are strings, but I am not sure.

I have now created another sheet that runs the following filter:

=FILTER('Members'!A2:C, ('Members'!C2:C + 365) < today())

Column C contains the date so the page effectively creates an email list. Now I just make a simpler script that runs each day, each column of the email list is used to populate the email.

I prefer this as it is less scripts to run and most of the work is done by the sheet.